# having trouble in join query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

I am trying to write a join query but its not working.

this is my model

```
 public function select_debate($channel_id)
  {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('TN_biaso');
$this->db->join('TN_show', 'TN_show.show_id = TN_biaso.biaso_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('channel_name', $channel_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: its returning the blank array

Answer (score 1):

Use

echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;

Copy the query and test it in phpmyadmin, it tells you whether you have any error in your query or not. let me know after the result. cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your where clause is getting an ambigious column `channel_name`. Try writing the `table_name`.`column_name` in the where clause just like in your join clause. i.e  `TN_biaso.channel_name` or `TN_show.channel_name`

Answer (score 0):

try like this in your where condition if your channel_name column in TN_biaso table

```
 public function select_debate($channel_id)
  {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('TN_biaso');
$this->db->join('TN_show', 'TN_show.show_id = TN_biaso.biaso_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('TN_biaso.channel_name', $channel_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

or if your channel_name column in TN_show table

```
  public function select_debate($channel_id)
      {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('TN_biaso');
    $this->db->join('TN_show', 'TN_show.show_id = TN_biaso.biaso_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('TN_show.channel_name', $channel_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result(); 
    }
```